# Calculus: prove $\int_0^t g(s) \sinh(k\int_s^t g(u)du)ds = \frac{1}{k}(\cosh(k\int_0^t g(u)du)-1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

Given:
$$f_1(t) = \int_0^t g(s) \sinh(k\int_s^t g(u)du)ds$$

$$f_2(t) = \frac{1}{k}(\cosh(k\int_0^t g(u)du)-1)$$

where $k$ is a positive constant, $g$ is an arbitrary continuous function.

How to prove: $f_1(t) = f_2(t)$?

I tried to take $d/dt$ to $f_2$ which gives:

$$g(t)\sinh(k\int_0^t g(u)du)$$

it is very similar formula to the integrand of $f_1$, but with a different lower limit of integration: $0$ instead of $s$.

I have no idea how to continue after doing this.

Comment: yes, thanks for correction

Comment: it is corrected

Comment: Thank you, Anne. You are correct. I am sorry, It is edited again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G(t)=\int_0^tg(u)du.$
$$\begin{align}f_1(t)&=\int_0^t\sinh\left(k(G(t)-G(s))\right)\,G'(s)ds\\
&=\int_{G(0)}^{G(t)}\sinh\left(k(G(t)-v)\right)\,dv\\
&=-\frac1k\left[\cosh\left(k(G(t)-v)\right)\right]_{G(0)}^{G(t)}\\
&=\frac1k\left(\cosh\left(k(G(t)-G(0))\right)-1\right)\\
&=f_2(t).
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you so much!